# Google apps script for sheets, how to create a 2-way link between two spreadsheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, synchronization

I'm attempting to write a script to continuously update two spreadsheets so that the information put in one always goes into the other.

The full project is to create a master spreadsheet with 50 people on it and each one of them has their own sheet/page, however they aren't allowed to access this master sheet as they are not allowed to see the other peoples data. (I am currently unaware of any viewing permission commands but I'm pretty sure there aren't any).

So the solution that I have been considering is creating 50 other spreadsheets and each of them will have a single sheet with all of the same information as the master Spreadsheet and the name of the sheet will be the same as on the master page.

I found this code on another post that was for a similar problem

```
function onEdit(e) {
  // Get the event object properties
  var range = e.range;
  var value = e.value;
  //Get the cell position 
  var row = range.getRowIndex();
  var column = range.getColumnIndex();
  exportValue(row,column,value)
}

function exportValue(row,column,value) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(targetID);
  var s = ss.getSheetByName(targetSheetName); 
  var target = s.getRange(row, column);
  target.setValue(value);
}
```

in this I understand what everything is doing except the ("var range = e.range; var value = e.value;") lines, is ths what im looking for or not, idk

Thanks in advance

:)

Comment: As that is written, each time they make a change the script reaches out to change the master spreadsheet. All well and good except they can't change it without access to it, so you won't be able to keep them out.  What kind of information are you doing here? A one way form would probably be the way to go, with a summary email function. Another option would indeed be you sharing 50 copies of the sheets and having a timed function that copies their sheet to your master every 12 hours or daily or weekly.

Comment: For your question, review Event objects in the documentation. As for the project, another alternative design is to create a web-app.

Comment: TheMaster can you elaborate, that's not particularly specific.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events

Comment: @J.G. is there a way that they can have the file in their google drive but it be in a locked folder for example, and the point of the master is not just for me to see, there are a group of people with access to that and they can change stuff on the master but all of the people that this information is about are strictly not to see other peoples information because of GDPR and confidentiality.

Comment: @TheMaster thanks for all your help, I now understand what all of the code is meant to do but I have reached my next problem, that the script just doesn't work.  I can get it to function perfectly copying from one sheet to another in the same spreadsheet but I cannot get it to work with the export.    this is the line in my code where it breaks currently (var s = SpreadsheetApp.openById(targetID).getSheetByName(targetSheet);) I have tested with loggers and found that everything up to this point works and all of the values are correct, this line just breaks and idky, thanks again

Comment: Yes, you can share the master with just a few other people, that isn't a problem. i'm not sure what you mean by a locked folder. But any scripting you do needs to be on the master sheet (reaching out for data from those other sheets you have access to) rather than their sheets reaching out to yours.

Comment: @J.G. Ok, that makes sense, thanks for your help

Comment: You need to provide [mcve] preferably in a new question.

Comment: @TheMaster ok will do, thanks anyway

Comment: @Cooper this one came first and I was instructed to create another question just fyi